# как вывести два поля в гридвью?

Tags: php, yii2

```
       если credit_up больше ноля то + зеленый, а если меньше то минус красный?
```

balance_up и credit_up соответственно тоже в две строки. Если изменение больше ноля, тогда добавь к значению +, если меньше - то там и так - (минус) будет.

}

```
[
                'attribute' => 'balance_up',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->balance_up . '<br>
                        <span class="text-success">' . $model->balance_up . '</span>
                      <span class="text-success">' . $model->credit_up . '</span>';
                    if($model->credit_up >= 0){
                        <span class="text-success"">'  +  '</span>';
                    }else{ <span class="text-danger"">'  -  '</span>';
}                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[
'attribute' => 'balance_up',
'format' => 'raw',
'value' => function($model) {
    return $model->balance_up . \yii\helpers\Html::tag('span', (($model->credit_up >= 0) ? '+' : '-'), [
      'class' => ($model->credit_up >= 0) ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'
    ]);
  }
]
```

Comment: только здесь выводится одно поле , а мне нужно два поля чтоб было balance_up и credit_up

Comment: обновил ответ. если что, можно хоть сколько полей ещё сконкатенировать после return $model->balance_up